# How do I automatically update a chart when a table gets a new record?

Tags: delphi, charts, data-aware

Suppose I have a table with a colour field — red/white/blue — and every time my app receives an event over TCP/IP and inserts a new row into the database, I want a data-aware pie chart component to auto-update showing the ratio of those colours. How can I do that?

I've seen examples of data-aware components, but they just show the value of each row of a table (I haven't gotten too far yet). In fact, I am not even sure that adding another row in the database will add another row to the DB-aware grid (push, as opposed to pull).

Comment: Which database and which kind of data aware controls?

Comment: Delphi already comes with [data-aware controls](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Data_Controls). For charts, there's TDBChart.

Comment: Did you look at the tutorials on the wiki, available at the same link as TOndrej posted, or click here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Tutorial:_Using_dbExpress_to_View_and_Update_Databases_in_an_Application

Comment: Mawg; FYI - The edits by Rob vastly improve the quality and readability of your answer. Note that all references to pizza pies are off topic on Stack overflow. Keep it pro, and keep it focused!

Comment: +1 to all. TMS & mySql. Apologies for levity. Thanks for the tutorial link.

Comment: @warrenp I thought that in the context of pie charts pizza references are surprisingly on topic :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am not even sure that adding another row in the database will add another row to the DB aware grid (push, as opposed to pull).

If the dataset is `live`, adding a row to the dataset will update the grid.

> Look, let's just imagine that I have a table who's primary key is a colour - red/white/blue - and every time my app receives an event over TCP/IP and inserts a new row into the database I want a data-aware pie chart component to auto-update showing the ratio of those colours.

1. Add a `Connection` to your form, set it up so it connects to your database.
2. Set the `connection` `active` property to `true`
3. Add a Query to your form, set the connection to `connection1`
4. Set the `sql` property to `SELECT (count(*) / b.totalcount) as percentage, b.totalcount FROM table1 a CROSS JOIN (select count(*) as totalcount from table1) b GROUP BY a.color`
5. Set the `active` property to `true`
6. Drop a `datasource` on the form, set its `dataset` to `query1`
7. Drop a DBChart on the form, set its `datasource` to `datasource1`
8. Fiddle with the DBChart to make it display a piechart.

Comment: +1 and the answer. Thanks for such a clear and helpful answer. I guessed that there ought to be a "live" option, otherwise the value of such components would be greatly diminished. And it's good to see that I can use the result of an SQL query in a DB component, not just the raw data.

Comment: For my next step, I will try to have a grid where each row of the grid is built up of several queries. But first I will read the tutorials and write some sample code and play around to get a feel for it. Thanks again for your help.